# SQL Server with clause versus temporary table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I could either do

```
select * into #randomTenUsers from
(select top 10 * from users)x    

select * from #randomTenUsers
```

OR

```
WITH randomTenUsers   as (select top 10 * from users)    

select * from randomTenUsers
```

From what I understand WITH statement also creates a temporary result set.

Is there a reason why WITH should be preferred over temp tables or vice versa?

Comment: There's no hard and fast rule as to when a CTE (WITH) is better or performs better than a temp table. If you need to have the data for multiple statements -> then you need a temp table, since the CTE only exists for the next statement. On the other hand, using a CTE is much easier and less cumbersome than setting up, filling, manipulation and ultimately dropping a temp table. So in the end: **it depends** on your concrete situation; if both approaches can do the job, I'd go with a CTE first, but if it's critical for performance, also test with a temp table and take a pick

Comment: We've had an instance where using a CTE gave us dramatically worse results than using a temp table. It's always worth trying both if your query works on lot of data (more than a few thousand rows).  Apparently this can be because SQL Server does not keep stats (like row count) for CTEs but it does for temp tables. That can result in suboptimal execution plans.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> From what I understand WITH statement also creates a temporary result
>   set.

No it does not. Using a CTE will not create a "temporary result set". There might be reasons for a query to create work tables but just because you are using a CTE is not one of them.

These two queries have an identical query plan and none of them creates a temporary result like a temp table in tempdb.

---

```
with randomTenUsers as
(
  select top 10 *
  from users
)    
select * 
from randomTenUsers;
```

---

```
select * 
from (
     select top 10 * 
     from users
     ) x;
```

---

As [marc_s said in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696487/sql-server-with-clause-versus-temporary-table#comment24030995_16696487), what you should use depends on what you want to do. There are situations where creating a temp table makes perfect sense and there are situations where it is completely unnecessary.

Comment: So what I gather is WITH statements are mainly to improve the readability of the code.

Comment: @Foo it can be reused in more places than one in the query. It can also be reused within it self to build a reqursive query.